# html tags not working inside response tags AJAX PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, response

I have a working code, using ajax, when an user types something into the input box, it will output 'hello' on the screen without having to press enter. However, there is a problem. Let me show you part of the working code first:

```
<?php

include('head.php');

echo "<response>";

echo "hello";

echo "</response>";

?>
```

^---The above code works, and outputs 'hello' on the screen whenever the user types something in the input box. The code for the input box, and everything else is on separate files, and will not be shown unless requested. The problem is that you cannot use html tags inside the response tags:

```
<?php

include('head.php');

echo "<response>";

echo "<i>"."hello"."</i>";

echo "</response>";

?>
```

^---The above code will output the word 'undefined', instead of the word 'hello' in italics. I don't know why it's doing that, so if anyone know why, and how to fix this, or if there is a workaround this problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Edit: Requested to show part of the code for ajax, in a separate file called test5.html:

```
<?php

include('ajax.php');

?>

<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="userInput" onKeyUp = "process('userInput','output','foodstore.php')"/>
<div id="output" />
</body>
</html>
```

More code in a file called ajax.php:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject){ 
try{
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}catch(e){
    xmlHttp = false;
}
}else{ 
try{
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch(e){
    xmlHttp = false;
}
}

if(!xmlHttp){
//alert("Cant create that object !")
}
else
return xmlHttp;
}

function process(text,output,link){

//text = 'userInput';

if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(text).value);
xmlHttp.open("GET", link+food,true);

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
handleServerResponse(text,output,link);
};

xmlHttp.send(null);
}else{
setTimeout("process(text,output,link)",1000);//cekaj 1s pa probaj opet
}
}

function handleServerResponse(text,output,link){

if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
if(xmlHttp.status==200){
    xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; //izvlaci se xml sto smo dobili
    xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
    message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
    document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = message;

setTimeout(function() {
    process(text,output,link);
}, 1000);

}else{
    //alert('Someting went wrong !');
}
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add "the code for the input box": currently it's hard to be sure of how you manage this. Notably because `<response>` tag make no sense, at least at a first view...

Comment: What is this `process()` function? It is most likely reading your PHP output as plain content. You'll have to share this process function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sending data to your response tag?

You should use `.html`

Your success function should look like this:

`function(data)
{
 $('response').html(data);
}`

Update:
XML content has to be update like this to include HTML within.

`<![CDATA[<i>Hello</i>]]>`